# The suffix くん with a girl's name

Tags: suffixes

> この間も『のりこ**くん**、お弁当買いに行ってくれないか』だって。

I know that the suffix くん is used with boys' names, while ちゃん is used with girls' names. But I've just listened to a dialogue between two girls, and one of them is talking about what her boss said to her.

Why is くん, not ちゃん, used with the girl's name？

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45066/chan-kun-what-is-used-currently-for-a-friend/45078#45078

Comment: Note that this type of くん is often seen as old-fashioned and pompous. See: https://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2010/0325/303778.htm

Comment: @naruto Really? I'd guess that a boss using くん is to avoid getting accused of  セクハラ.

Comment: @ratchetfreak For that purpose, we can just stick to さん regardless of sex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> one of them is talking about what her boss said to her.

This is very important context. `くん` can be used by a boss for a subordinate regardless of their gender. Outside of workplace, it can also be used in other hierarchical settings, e.g. a teacher talking to a student or a school club's president speaking to a club member.

However, as [mentioned by @naruto](https://komachi.yomiuri.co.jp/t/2010/0325/303778.htm), especially in workplace it seems to be going out of fashion, in part exactly due to the potential confusion about the person's gender. The gender-neutral さん is likely the better option nowadays.